# Como listar os aniversariantes dos últimos 7 dias com crystal reports e c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

Estou a desenvolver um sistema de gestão de Igreja, e preciso pegar todos os fieis cadastrados no sistema, cujo seu aniversário encontra-se nos últimos 7 dias, a contar com a data actual.
Já criei as seguintes formulas:

```
CDate ({FIEIS.DataNasc_fl})>=CurrentDate-7

CDate ({FIEIS.DataNasc_fl})>=Last7Days
```

Tanto a primeira como a segunda formula, não resultaram.
Se alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer, agradeço imenso!

@Motta! tentei do jeito que postaste, deu erro na formula:

Answer (score 0):

```
(totext({Comando.NASC},"MMdd") >= totext(CurrentDate-7,"MMdd") and
 totext({Comando.NASC},"MMdd") <= totext(CurrentDate,"MMdd"))
```

Exemplo que fiz aqui e funcionou

Comment: ! Tentei do jeito que postaste, não deu certo. Está a dar um erro.

Comment: Também estou a notar a presença de parenteses a mais.

Comment: não seria a menos? totext((CurrentDate),"yyyyMM")

Comment: Também já fiz assim, continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pessoal! Também pode ser da seguinte forma: Colocar dois datetimepicker (datainicio e datafim), para poder fazer a busca num determinado periodo. Para o CR pegue as datas como parametros. Se alguem souber, também agradeço. Apesar que a prioridade é mesmo a primeira forma.

Comment: Alterei meu exemplo , basta trocar seu nome de campo

Comment: Pessoal! mexi na formula e ficou assim: totext({FIEIS.DataNasc_fl}) >= totext((CurrentDate-7),"dd-MM") and
totext({FIEIS.DataNasc_fl}) <= totext((CurrentDate),"dd-MM"). No Crystal reports não encontra erro. Mas quando selecciono a referida formula no selection expert e no value ponho true, o relatório aparece em branco.

Comment: @Motta. Voltei a tentar depois da alteração, com Basic Syntax seleciona o primeiro parentese e dá o seguinte erro: A statement is required here. Com Crystal Syntax dá o seguinte erro: Too many arguments have been given to this function.

Comment: Tem de ser MMdd pois assim mantém a hierarquia da data , a solução que fiz funcionou para um campo DATE aplicado no Filtro de Registro. e tem de ter o "totext" nas duas pontas do teste para que se compare coisas homogêneas (datas convertidas em string de mês e dia)

Comment: @Motta! Estou usando o Crystal reports que vem embutido no VS2008. Será que a versão do Crystal Reports tem alguma  infuência? Porque já tentei fazer do jeito que está no código melhorado por ti, e continua dando erro.

Comment: Quando removo "MMdd" da formula, o CR não encontra nenhum erro nela, mas o relatório aparece vazio.

Comment: O meu campo é DateTime. Será que faz questão?

Comment: "faz questão" seria o nosso "faz diferença" ? (risos) , creio que não , deveria funcionar pois o totext fará a conversão. Qual a fonte de dados ? Uma solução poderia ser via query , usando (por exemplo) o EXTRACT month/day FROM  ...

Comment: Aqui em Angola, usamos tanto uma como a outra expressão para o efeito (risos). Como seria exactamente esta outra solução?

Answer (score 0):

**FINALMENTE CONSEGUI PESSOAL!** Fiz da seguinte forma:

**1) Criei 4 SQL Expression Fields:**

data1: {fn DAYOFYEAR("FIEIS"."DataNasc_fl")})

data2:({fn DAYOFYEAR({fn CURDATE()})}-7)

data3:{fn DAYOFYEAR("FIEIS"."DataNasc_fl")}

data4:{fn DAYOFYEAR({fn CURDATE()})}.

**2) Criei uma formula** "ult7dias" que ficou assim:

{%data1}>={%data2} and {%data3}<={%data4}

E funcionou! Está a pegar os aniversariantes dos últimos 7 dias!!!
Muito obrigado ao brothers que me deram dicas nesta questão, especialmente ao @Motta. Espero contar sempre convosco nas próximas dúvidas que eu tiver.